# Toggle Markers with Google Maps API (XML)

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have been pulling my hair out over this. I'm trying to toggle the markers on my map with the click of a button. The examples I have seen online are using JSON, and I'm using XML to pull my data, does this make any difference?

```js
function load() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.507664, -0.150174);
  var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,        
            zoom: 15,
            scrollwheel: true,
            zoomControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            panControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,        
            styles: stylesArray,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap' }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  downloadUrl("inc/map.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        title: name,
        visible: true,
        type: type,
        icon: icon.icon
      });

      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);

    }
  });
}


function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
```

**The XML file is being created with this file:**

```php
    $map = "fW2sxnzi";

// Start XML file, create parent node

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server

$connection=mysql_connect ('localhost', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());}

// Set the active MySQL database

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table

$query = "SELECT * FROM places WHERE map_id = '$map'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

I'm pulling the markers and their details from a database and I'm looking to toggle them by 'type' that will be either 1, 2, 3 or 4.

Comment: Not at my comp. Sorry but I found it easier to push all the markers for each group into an array and then you can set the array to the map to show them or set the array to null to hide them.

Comment: Thanks @JesseRules That sounds interesting, would you be able to provide an example at a later date? I think I may have shot my self in the foot using XML but it's what Google suggests.

Comment: Yeah,  Ill put my code up in a couple hours.

Answer (score 1):

So, this is in Ext Js but I think you'll get it.

I made a global array:

```
  var fireDeptMarkers = [];
```

Then I added a checkbox but the same would work for a button or toggle:

```
{
        xtype: 'checkbox',
        fieldLabel: 'Fire Departments',
        itemId: 'fireDepartments',
        labelWidth: 200,
        width: 300
    },
```

I use the MVC model so here's the controller for this. Instead of doing it inline I just used this to call the function in the controller:

```
  '#fireDepartments': {
            change: this.fireDepartmentsChanged
        },
```

Here's the actual function where it adds the markers or removes them.
The last part after I make the markers is where I push them into the global fireDemartments array and then I can just go though the array and setmap to null to hide them.

One thing I am going to go back and fix after looking at this is that I load the store every time the button is clicked to add them. I should probably make it where if it's already loaded to just use the existing data.  But I think this covers how I added and removed the markers on button click.

```
fireDepartmentsChanged: function (checked) {
    if (checked.value == true) {
        var a = Ext.getStore('fireDepartment_s');
        a.load({
            callback: function () {

                Ext.each(Ext.getStore('fireDepartment_s').data.items, function (record) {

                    var latitude = record.data.location_lat;
                    var longitude = record.data.location_lng;
                    var address = record.data.address;
                    var department = record.data.department;

                    var contentString = '<body><p><b>' + department + '</b></p><p> ' + address + '</p>' +
                       '<button onclick="streetView(' + latitude + ',' + longitude + ')">Street View</button><p id="streetView"></p> ' +
                       '</body>';

                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: contentString,
                    });


                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                        icon: 'resources/images/fireDeptIcon.png',
                        map: map
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });

                    fireDeptMarkers.push(marker);

                });
            }
        });
    }

    else if (checked.value === false) {

        for (i = 0; i < fireDeptMarkers.length; i++) {
            fireDeptMarkers[i].setMap(null);
        }
    }
},
```